# How to check number of variable arguments passed to any function?

Tags: c, arguments, variadic-functions, variadic

I have a program where I am defining a new print function to print some data in required format. Am passing variable arguments of both integer and string data types. Before printing string type i want to check whether how many arguments are passed and type of argument. Else if i pass integer by mistake and try to print in string format then i see segmentation fault
Below is my code;

```
void my_print(int log, int flags,....)
{ 
   /* ----------------------
   ----------------------
   ---------------------- */
}
```

Before printing my arguments in required format, I want to check the number of arguments passed to this function. Sometimes I pass 5 arguments and sometimes I pass 6 arguments.

So is there any function in C language to check total number of arguments passed to this function?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Just as printf etc uses the format string, you must pass some indication of the number of parameters that are _supposed_ to follow.

Answer (score 1):

By *definition* (read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)) any [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (such as `printf`) should know when to stop fetching arguments : see [stdarg(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html).

The usual way is to have a discriminating prefix argument (like [syslog(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) does). You could have other conventions (e.g. store in some global variable something describing the call, use C macros, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of variable arguments requires that the number of arguments is otherwise known.
An example is the format string of `printf()`, which implies the number without actually giving it.
You could also simply specify the number in an additional integer parameter before the variable arguments - because afterwards would of course not work, since you'd need to know the number to find the parameter which provides it.